# Javascript Debugger implemented in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

### Use-Case

- An online development environment
- The development environment is implemented using JavaScript
- The development environment enable creation of JavaScript code
- The development environment enable debugging of the created JavaScript

**Is there an existing solution I can integrate with my product to support online JavaScript debugging for Java script created by my online dev env web-site ?**

**UPDATE:** I don't think the question was clear enough, The JavaScript code I want to debug is created by my web-page ( a textbox with JavaScript inside ), using the browser debugger will enable debugging of my web-site and not the script created by it (the one in the textbox).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript already has a debugger built in.

You can use the `developer console` of a browser by typing `debugger;` in your code to break the code and start debugging from that point. Just open your console, reload the page and your debugger will start.

So an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_debugger):

```
var x = 15 * 5;
debugger;
document.getElementbyId("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

More info at the [w3cschools page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)

This will break your code and it will look like this in your console:

[image: debugger image]

To the right you will see the controls. There you have the standard controls like `hop over`, `hop in`, ...

[image: Control panel]

**Edit:** So you seem to be re inventing the hot water. But if you take jsfiddle as example you see it does work. It *IS* debugging the script made by the user. Take [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3p69avq9/) as example. Open your console and run the script. You will see the debugger *IS* started on the script. And *NOT* on the page. You just have to let the user add `debugger;` to their script and create a way for your web page to run that code.

Comment: My web page is used to create JavaScript code, I want to be able to debug the javascript code created by my web-page, using the integrated debugger will enable debugging of my online dev environment and not the script I have created with it

Comment: @NadavRub Normally not. If you create a script on your web page and add the debugger in that script you made. It will debug only that script and not your dev enviroment.

Comment: @NadavRub I updated my answer. If this is not what you are looking for I don't think there is another solution since I have never used/heard from an other JS debugger other than the build in one.